# load data from an external file on my pc

Tags: highcharts

I have a problem with a `highstock` chart. I need for my university project to show a real time chart of values that I can find in a log on my PC.

I downloaded the highstock zip from the site and studied the examples. In particular I'm trying to modify the dynamic update `index.html`

How can I replace the random function for `y` value for get the data from my csv file?

This is the original code:

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    chart : {
        events : {
            load : function() {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function() {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                    y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    },
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I advice to prepare www server, where you will keep your files, then load in your machine by $.get().

Comment: Can you show me a little code example for better understand how to use $.get() for push a single int value (from csv file) in y? Thank you!